# Could not compile source code

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm trying to run my code but I get this error:

Could not compile the source code.

Undeclared identifier.
    require(available);
            ^-------^
However, I defined 'available' as a boolean in a struct

```
struct Car{
  address  VechileOwner;
  string make;
  string model;
  Renter renter;
  bool available;
  uint pricePerDay;
  uint deposit;
  uint entrycode;
  uint minRentalDay;
  uint maxRentalDay;
 }
```

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the full source code? In the above snippet there's no error.

Comment: Please go to this link  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37457/car-rental-system-compile-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Car Rental System Compile Error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37457/car-rental-system-compile-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use variable (or boolean) inside the struct in example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Car {

    struct car {
      bool available;
    }

    car audi;

    function Car() public {
        audi = car(true);
    }

    function checkAvailability() public view returns (bool) {
        return(audi.available);
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, you cannot just use `require(available);`; you need to assign the struct as `some_name` and then use `require(some_name.available)`.