# Car Rental System Compile Error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, compiler, error

I am writing code for a car rental system but i'm getting a few compile error messages that don't understand.

The first error is

> TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.

The second is

> TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type
>   function () view external returns (address).

The third is

> TypeError: Operator < not compatible with types uint256 and function
>   () view external returns (uint256).

Here's my code:

PLEASE NOTE: The asterisk represents which line in the code errors.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract rentCar {

    struct Renter {
        address  addr;
        uint DOB;
        uint currentRenting;
    }

    bool public rented;
    address public owner;
    uint public duration;
    uint public rentalPrice;
    uint public charge;
    uint public rentalDate;
    uint public returnDate;
    uint public rentalStartDate;
    uint public rentalEndDate;
    uint public constant totalDays = 7;


    struct NameKey{ // storage the name's keys
        uint[] keys;
    }

    //List of Cars available
    uint[] private ids;  //Use it to return the ids of Objects
    uint public numofCars;
    mapping(uint => Car) private cars;
    mapping(string => NameKey) private nameToKeys;

    //Events
    event E_addCar(uint objID, address VechileOwner);
    event E_Rent(address indexed _renter, uint _rentalDate, uint _returnDate, uint _rentalPrice);
    event E_ReturnRental(address indexed _renter, uint _returnDate);

    //Modifiers
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    /*
    modifier onlyRenter() {
        require(msg.sender == addr);
        _;
    }
    */
    modifier whenNotRented() {
        require(!rented);
        _;
    }

    modifier whenRented() {
        require(rented);
        _;
    }

    //Funcions

    function rentCar() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function addCar(string make, string model, uint pricePerDay, uint minRentalDay, uint maxRentalDay, bool available) public onlyOwner {

        Car newCar = cars[numofCars];
        ///nameToKeys[name].keys.push(numofCars); //add the key to the name's keys
        ///***ERRORS
        newCar.VechileOwner = msg.sender;
        newCar.make = make;
        newCar.model = model;
        newCar.available = available;
        newCar.pricePerDay = pricePerDay;
        newCar.minRentalDay = minRentalDay;
        newCar.maxRentalDay = maxRentalDay;

        newCar(numofCars,msg.sender);
        ids.push(numofCars);
        numofCars++;

    }

    function setAvailable(uint objID, bool _available) public view onlyOwner {
        ///***ERRORS
        cars[objID].available = _available;
    }

    /* function totalDays (uint rentalStartDate, uint rentalEndDate) public whenNotRented{
        uint totalDays = ;
        return totalDays;
    }*/

    function Rent(uint objID,uint totalDays) public payable  whenNotRented returns(bool){
        ///***ERRORS
        require (msg.value < cars[objID].deposit);
        require(totalDays >= cars[objID].minRentalDay && totalDays <= cars[objID].maxRentalDay);


        cars[objID].renter = Renter({addr:msg.sender, currentRenting:now});

        uint PayDeposit = msg.value - cars[objID].deposit;
        rentalPrice = totalDays *  cars[objID].pricePerDay;
        rentalDate = rentalStartDate;
        returnDate = rentalEndDate;

        cars[objID].available = false;
        rented = true;

        // accessCar();

        ///***ERRORS
        E_Rent(Renter, rentalDate, returnDate, rentalPrice);

        return true;
    }

    function endRent (uint objID, uint duration) public  whenRented {
        ///***ERRORS
        duration = (now - cars[objID].renter.currentRenting) / (24*60*60*1.0);
        charge = duration * cars[objID].priceDaily - cars[objID].deposit;
        uint totalPayment = msg.value - charge;

        require(!cars[objID].VechileOwner.send(charge));
        require(!cars[objID].renter.addr.send(charge));

        delete cars[objID].renter;
        cars[objID].available = false;

        E_ReturnRental(Renter, now);

        resetRental();
    }

    function forceRentalEnd() public onlyOwner{
        require(now > returnDate && rented);

        E_ReturnRental(Renter, now);

        resetRental();
    }

    function resetRental() private{
        rented = false;
        Renter.addr = address(0);
        rentalDate = 0;
        returnDate = 0;
    }
}
```

I have a second contract called Car that interacts with the other contract

```
contract  Car is rentCar {
    address public VechileOwner;
    string public make;
    string public model;
    Renter public renter;

    bool public available;
    uint public pricePerDay;
    uint public deposit;
    uint public entrycode;
    uint public minRentalDay;
    uint public maxRentalDay;

    function checkAvailability() public view returns (bool) {
        return(Car.available);
    }

    function Car(string _make, string _model, uint _pricePerDay, uint _minRentalDay, uint _maxRentalDay, bool _available) public onlyOwner{
        make = _make;
        model = _model;
        pricePerDay = _pricePerDay;
        minRentalDay = _minRentalDay;
        maxRentalDay = _maxRentalDay;
        available = _available;
    }  
}
```

I'd really appreciate the help.

Here are the error messages that appear on remix:
[image: Error messages are shown on online compilier]
[image: Error messages are shown on online compilier]
[image: Error messages are shown on online compilier]
[image: Error messages are shown on online compilier]

Many thanks

Comment: Your contract has other errors and is incomplete, it is missing `Car` definition and `resetRental()` function. Can you split your contract into smaller parts so it is easier to test and verify your error messages?

Comment: @Ismael i have added the rest of my code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to literally split the contract, but to trim the contract to a minimal example that shows the problem. I usually paste the contracts into remix.ethereum.org and check there the error messages.

Comment: is this what you meant

Comment: I've reformated your contract to make them easier to read and check for errors with remix. Also replaced the `*` in the errors with comments `///***ERRORS` so they don't cause syntax errors. Check if you think is something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors the most notorious is to declare `Car` as a contract.

> ```
> TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
>     newCar.VechileOwner = msg.sender;
>     ^-----------------^
> ```

Here `newCar` is an instance of `Car` a contract, you cannot access directly a variable of another contract.

```
    Car newCar = cars[numofCars];
    newCar.VechileOwner = msg.sender;
```

Solidity will create getters for public variables but it will not create setters you have to create them explicitely.

> ```
>  TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type function () view external returns (address).
>     newCar.VechileOwner = msg.sender;
>                           ^--------^
> ```

Here the problems is that `VechileOwner` is the getter (a function), and you are trying to assign them an address. This is not possible.

> ```
> TypeError: Operator < not compatible with types uint256 and function () view external returns (uint256)
>     require (msg.value < cars[objID].deposit);
>              ^-----------------------------^
> ```

A similar problem here `cars[objID].deposit` is a getter, and you are comparing it with an `uint`, it doesn't have any meaning.

IMHO a better solution is to declare `Car` a struct inside `rentCar` contract.

```
struct  Car {
    address VechileOwner;
    string make;
    string model;
    Renter renter;

    bool available;
    uint pricePerDay;
    uint deposit;
    uint entrycode;
    uint minRentalDay;
    uint maxRentalDay;
}
```

This cause other problems with the current code.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to have a look at my code. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use the `view` modifier, you **can't** change the state. Any state change will result in an error. `view` is used for static calls only. For instance, your `setAvailable()` function will clearly fail since you change the `cars` variable state with `cars[objID].available = _available;`.

For the rest, I think there are some issues with your Struct calls, where is your Car struct defined?

Comment: there no struct defined, it is been called from the contract 'Car'.